# AFNetworking check response

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, response, afnetworking-2

How to check if the response is returned :

> HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily
>
> Server: nginx/1.5.6
>
> Date: Wed, 18 Mar 2015 19:23:02 GMT
>
> Content-Type: text/html
>
> Transfer-Encoding: chunked
>
> Connection: keep-alive
>
> Last-Modified: Wed, 18 Mar 2015 19:23:02 GMT
>
> Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=1oh16nbnn9anin3r71tcsmo804; path=/
>
> Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
>
> Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0,
>   pre-check=0
>
> Pragma: no-cache
>
> Set-Cookie: er_referer=deleted; expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:01 GMT
>
> Set-Cookie: S_ID=1061662561; path=/
>
> Location: /core/

request code :

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
    manager.responseSerializer = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];
    AFHTTPRequestSerializer * requestSerializer = [AFHTTPRequestSerializer serializer];
    [requestSerializer setValue:ua forHTTPHeaderField:@"User-Agent"];
    manager.requestSerializer = requestSerializer;
    AFHTTPResponseSerializer * responseSerializer = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];
    manager.responseSerializer = responseSerializer;
    NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"login": myLogin, @"pass": myPassword};
    [manager POST:urlLogin parameters:parameters success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        if ([operation.responseString rangeOfString:@""].location == NSNotFound) {
            NSLog(@"Login or password false");
        } else {
```

If the response html I'm doing like this `if ([operation.responseString rangeOfString: @ "Then I put the titel"]. Location == NSNotFound)`, but do not know how to do in this case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Foundation URL Loading System will automatically redirect your request to the path specified in the `Location` header.

If you need to intercept the redirect, usually to handle an authentication issue, you can set an authentication challenge block (and if necessary, a redirect response block) on the `operation` object.

[Here's an AFNetworking GitHub issue](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/issues/514) in which this issue is discussed. It has some sample code if you need it.

Comment: I need to check if the 302 came, then continue to execute `} else {
            browserWindowController = [[ERBrowserWindowController alloc] initWithWindowNibName:@"ERBrowserWindowController"];
            [browserWindowController showWindow:self];
            [browserWindowController addDefaultTabs];` And if it came to a different code to display a message : "Login or password false"